# HTML5 Dataset not working well with IE(9)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, dataset

I have an ajax call that calls a php script to bring some thumbnail images down, along with some information about the thumbnails, like the size of the full image. This data is put into an HTML table. $bigwidth and $bigheight are the full size of the image and are encoded into the thumbnail `img` tag by using the HTML5 dataset attribute:

```
 echo ("<td class='galleryThumbContainer'>
            <div class='imgWrapper'>
                <img class='galleryThumb' src=$file_url data-bigwidth='$bigwidth' data-bigheight='$bigheight' help_token='gallery thumb' title='Double-click to crop. Delete at upper right corner.'>
            </div>
          </td>");
```

On the client side, when I drop the thumbnail into a jQuery UI droppable container, my script pulls out and uses the bigwidth value, using either lines 1 and 2 below or lines 5 and 6.

```
1.    var thumb$ = ui.draggable;        // wrapped set of thumb being dropped
2.    var bigwidth = thumb$.data('bigwidth');     // works
3.          
4.       /*  Test Code  */
5.    var thumb = ui.draggable[0];              // the raw thumb node
6.    var bigwidth2 = thumb.dataset.bigwidth;      // breaks: thumb.dataset is undefined
7.       /* end test code  */
```

Either method works for Chrome and Firefox, but only the first method works for IE(9). With IE9 the second method sees `thumb.dataset` as undefined.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dataset property is not supported for IE9, only the latest version (IE11) supports this. As stated on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).

Another method for you to obtain the value for an attribute that works on all major browsers is:

```
thumb.getAttribute('data-bigwidth')
```

Comment: Thanks for straightening that out.  I suspect the jQuery version worked because jQuery is smart enough to recognize 'name' in .data('name') as an attribute, if that's what it is, (and it is here) and return the attribute value.